# New dataset.map transformation and lookup table: incompatible string type

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm looking forward to use the [new `Dataset` API](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.2/tensorflow/contrib/data) available in 1.2 but I'm facing issues when applying a simple `map` transformation that looks up words in an [index table](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/lookup).

Consider this simple example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

mapping_strings = tf.constant(["emerson", "lake", "palmer"])
table = tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_tensor(
    mapping=mapping_strings, num_oov_buckets=1)

dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    tf.constant(["emerson", "lake"]))

# Here is the map operation that generates an error.
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: table.lookup(x))

iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
    sess.run(next_element)
```

**With `1.2.0-rc2`, it generates the following error:**

```
TypeError: In op 'string_to_index_Lookup/hash_table_Lookup', input types ([tf.string, tf.string, tf.int64]) are not compatible with expected types ([tf.string_ref, tf.string, tf.int64])
```

The lookup table expects a `tf.string_ref` and this requirement does not appear to be met.

As I'm new to TensorFlow I don't suspect this to be a bug but a bad usage. What is my mistake?

Thanks!

**EDIT 2017-06-15: With a `nightly` version, however, it throws another error:**

```
ValueError: Cannot capture a stateful node (name:string_to_index/hash_table, type:HashTableV2) by value.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use `Dataset.make_initializable_iterator()` instead of `Dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()` because the hash table is stateful.

Following code worked for me:

```
import tensorflow as tf

mapping_strings = tf.constant(["emerson", "lake", "palmer"])
table = tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_tensor(
  mapping=mapping_strings, num_oov_buckets=1)

dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
  tf.constant(["emerson", "lake"]))

# Here is the map operation that generates an error.
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: table.lookup(x))

iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
init_op = iterator.initializer

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
  sess.run(init_op)
```

Comment: I believe this works as long as you upgrade to the very latest (nightly) version of TensorFlow. There was a bug in the last release candidate for 1.2.0 where some deprecated kernels (using the old-style `tf.string_ref` instead of `tf.resource`) continued to be used in `tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_tensor()`, and these are now fixed up to use the new versions in the master branch.

Comment: Thank you both. So the fix is to upgrade TensorFlow and use the iterator initializer. I updated my question to reflect the error one would get with a version of TensorFlow without the bug @mrry mentioned and I'm accepting Satoshi's answer.

Comment: The `tf.string_ref` bug is still present in 1.2.0 final.